# How to set decimal separator in MS Access using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, decimal, separator

My software creates PAIN001.XML files directly from an Access financial database. The decimal separator must always be a dot. The numbers are formatted with:

```
MyText = Format(MyNumber, "#0.00")
```

However, the format string's dot is automatically replaced by the system decimal separator, which might be "," instead of "." !

In Excel there are easy solutions, for example:

```
Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
...
```

However, MS Access doesn't recognize this application property.
**Is there a simple way to define a decimal separator within Access vba code ?**

Of course, one can create a function which scans each MyText number for wrong decimal separators and replaces them with a dot, but this function would have to be called separately for each number, slowing down the code quite a lot…

Answer (score 2):

> The decimal separator must always be a dot.

Then use **Str**:

```
MyText = Str(MyNumber)
```

To convert such a string to a number use **Val**:

```
MyNumber = Val(MyText)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't resolve the question because when making text from numbers, Access always uses the default decimal separator. This is also the case when using MyText=Format(123, "#0.00"): the "." is not interpreted as dot, but as decimal separator - that is, MyText is 123,00 when the decimal separator is "," !

Comment: It certainly does answer your original question. Of course, it doesn't answer your new question. And your assumption, that Access (VBA) always uses the default decimal separator, is not correct. See edited answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is not solveable with the decimal separator `Application.DecimalSeparator = "."`, even if it was supported by the Access library. It is a rather complicated issue, for the non-US users, as we are used to have `,` as a decimal separator.

In general, VBA considers only `.` as a decimal separator. Without taking care of the application default separator, the location of the user and their settings. Thus, some interesting cases could happen:

[image]

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim myText As String
    myText = "123,42"
    Debug.Print Replace(Format(myText, "#0.00"), ",", ".")
End Sub
```

A possible solution, that I have implemented some time ago was to use `Replace()` and to replace as in the gif above. It could be a bit slow indeed, but taking into account the usage of VBA and Access, extreme speed is not something the app could achieve anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed this is the only way around the problem. To minimize the impact on speed, I implemented it by first retrieving once the system decimal separator
DecSep=Right((Format(0, "0."), 1)
then calling a formatting function BankSum(Amount,DecSep) each time necessary:
If DecSep = "." Then
BankSum = Format(Amount, "#0.00")
Else
BankSum = Replace(Format(Amount, "#0.00"), DecSep, ".")
End If
As formatting is done in a single step, the effect on speed is negligible.
NB: in Switzerland both "." or "," are usual - but for internet banking XML files this must always be "." !

Comment: @Bughater - well, if it works for you, then its ok. Still, think of some input, using thausands separator like `100.000,32`. This may really hit the fan.